# Perform transform on element with active animation

Tags: css, animation, transform

I have an element with active animation going on:

```
#preloader .circle-outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 94px;
    height: 94px;
    margin: -47px 0 0 -47px;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: spinOffPulse 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spinOffPulse{
    0%{transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100%{transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

When my preloader stops loading, I want to set a special class, and then animate my .circle-outer using this code:

```
#preloader.loaded .circle-outer {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

But it doesn't work. If I turn off an animation, everything works fine, but can I do transform on 'animation' active element? Even if I don't, how can I achieve this kind of effect?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the animation's code? I think that you need to specify a keyframe with the transform property

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I've updated my code. The thing is that I want to keep object rotating while scaling up. And start that animation only after certain event (class added by JS)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
 @keyframes spinOffPulse{
     0%{transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);}
     100%{transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);}  
 }
```

It works:

http://jsfiddle.net/y5jtyod4/

Comment: Thanks! it' working nice. The problem is that I have an animation that already going on (the one that I provided in question) and I need to change it on a fly, so it keeps spinning and then scale.

p.s. I came up with solution using jQuery for this. Important note - keep the same timing function and use animation-fill-mode:forwards